# Foursquare Venue Api: info to generate "8/10 people like this place"

Tags: foursquare

When looking at FourSquare pages (e.g: [Place Vendome, Paris](https://foursquare.com/v/place-vend%C3%B4me/4adcda09f964a5200e3421e3)) the text: "9.4/10 People like this place" is shown. I'd like to get to this information through the Foursquare api. I'm  guessing it's the calculation: `likes/(likes + dislikes)` . All fine, but although `nr of likes` is available `nr of dislikes` doesn't seem to be. (Looking at the venue Api btw, which seems logical)

Am I glancing over something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 9.4/10 rating is computed from an algorithm  that includes a variety of signals beyond likes/dislikes. You can use the venues/detail endpoint to get the numerical value of the rating.

Comment: sounds good, but I can't find it here https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/venue ?

Comment: ahh I see it's indeed there but undocumented.. `response.venue.rating` .. Thanks