# Different result order in Foursquare API's explore endpoint

Tags: foursquare

I'm trying to use Foursquare's */venues/explore* API endpoint, to retrieve the 5 "best" places (topPicks) within a 300 meter radius from a geographic point. However, I'm getting different results back  when I do the same requests multiple times after each other.

For example requests to the following endpoint:

```
/venues/explore?openNow=0&time=any&radius=300&sortByDistance=0&day=any&ll=59.3181690597,18.0636363477&limit=5&v=20130911&section=topPicks
```

When I did two requests to this endpoint within seconds of each other I first got the following venues back:

```
Marie Laveau
Drop Coffee
Kaffe(bar)
Seriegalleriet
Mariatorget
```

and then

```
Mariatorget
Drop Coffee
Kaffe(bar)
Seriegalleriet:
Stora Vikingen
```

I'm doing the requests with an application access token, so the result shouldn't be tailored for a specific user.

Is there a way to make the */venues/explore* endpoint behave more deterministic? For example a way to make the results ordered by Foursquare's score?

Comment: Sorry about the long response. This is actually a bug and we're looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

I [found out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616351/foursquare-venue-api-info-to-generate-8-10-people-like-this-place) that Foursquare actually returns the rating in venue responses (even though it's [undocumented](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/venue)).

My current solution is therefore to request many more venues from the explore endpoint, sort the results by venue rating, and then pick the five with the highest score. It's probably not a perfect solution, but it's the best I've come up with so far.