# Rating venues (Foursquare)

Tags: java, foursquare

I am developing a Java application that involves the use of Foursquare to search for venues. The application is expected to rate the venues as well. I have done everything I need to do except including the ratings of venues. I read the suggestions to make use of likes and dislikes of foursquare to determine rating. Either the API didn't expose that or I don't know how to do that.Any code snippet that will provide me with hint on how to do that will help.
I am using the following URL
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search
I expected the rating to be included in the response but I can't access it from the object of Compactvenue

```
for (CompactVenue venue : result.getResult().getVenues()) {
        // TODO: Do something we the data
        System.out.println(venue.getName()+"\t"+venue.getUrl());

      }
```

The following link shows the possible methods in Compact Venue
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/venue

I only need the code snippet to include the rating so that I can complete my program.

Please how do I make a separate venue detail call. Please throw more light on it. I can only call methods in foursquareApi and probably include callbackurl in the constructor.

Comment: Some desription is needed of what APIs you have tried out. And what syntax of API you expect for your remaining requirement. Suggestion type questions won't be entertained by senior members. Not the right place for them!

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616351/foursquare-venue-api-info-to-generate-8-10-people-like-this-place

Comment: TechSpellBound, please show me if you know it. I have been struggling for this for more than a week now. I only need how to retrieve the ratings of the venues.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that venue details only give a compact venue response. To get fuller info we have about a venue through the API, you need to make a separate [venue detail](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/venues) call. Take a look at your Java library's documentation on how to do that.

Sometimes venues don't have ratings.

Comment: Please how do I make a separate venue detail call. Please throw more light on it. I can only call methods in foursquareApi and probably include callbackurl in the constructor.

Comment: That would depend on the individual Java library you're using. If it's the `fi.foyt.foursquare.api` one, I believe the method is just called `venue` and you pass in a venue ID that you got from the search